# KDB script keeps crashing

Tags: kdb

I've been finding recently that my KDB launch script is crashing.  I need to restart my computer and then it will run fine.  I launch KDB from a CMD prompt and I can't figure out where to look to see what process is running in the background which is causing it to crash.  Does anybody know what I should check?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, we'd need more info to diagnose this - what OS, what kdb version, how are you starting it, are you running it in the background or foreground etc. Does it error when you start a kdb instance in a terminal in the foreground?

Comment: Sorry, I got this installed a long time ago and now just run it and do the query coding so I'm not too familiar with how even to check the KDB version.  I'm running Windows 10 and have a batch script that I launch to run kdb server.  I then use QpadInsight as a GUI interface to run my queries.   Here is the text in the Windows batch file I run.  REM set KDBALB=c:\q\files
REM set KDBPORT=9999
set QHOME=C:\q
set QINIT=C:\q\ServerFiles\server.q
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\q\w32
q -p 9999

REM launch the discovery service
REM start "KDB" q %KDBALB% -p %KDBPORT%

Comment: Also if I go to c:\q\w32 I just see the application q but it has no version details.  Normally when I run the script I see a CMD window that says q) and I leave that open and go to QpadInsight.

Comment: There is usually a banner when you start a q session that would give you the version or you can run .z.K to see what version you are running

Comment: KDB+ version is 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Trying running a blank kdb instance with just:

```
set QHOME=C:\q
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\q\w32

and then

q -p 1234
```

(doesn't need to be in a batch script, you should be able to just run those commands in a cmd prompt). If kdb comes up then kdb isn't the problem.

Then try to manually load the startup script to see if the problem is there:

```
q)system"l C:\\q\\ServerFiles\\server.q"
```

If this works fine then the problem isn't there. The last place it can be is in the database/directory load, so load that:

```
q)system"l c:\\q\\files"
```

If none of these cause an error then something else is affecting your kdb instance, either something running on a timer (check `.z.ts`) or something is connecting externally

Comment: Thanks, so it seems the issue is in the database/directory load as everything worked fine until I pasted the last bit of code. I'm not even sure why I have the line in my script REM set KDBALB=c:\q\files -  q)system"l c:\\q\\files"
'c:\q\files. OS reports: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
  [0]  system"l c:\\q\\files"

Comment: The actual data that KDB pulls is specified in the server file.  For example the first line of the server file is: customers: ("SSSSSSSSSDFFFDDFS"; enlist ",") 0:`d:/dropbox/q/files/customers.csv;

Comment: Ok so yes, something is bad in your files directory. The only objects in there should be kdb-loadable objects (kdb tables, .q scripts, kdb-serialised objects). If you don't need it you can try removing the load of that directory by removing that "KDBALB" variable from your start script. Another thing I noticed - your original code sample mixes lower case "c" and upper case "C" for the C drive - could that be an issue too or is it not case sensitive?

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the KDBALB line.  I had to restart the computer yesterday so it was working even with it but the good news is the script did work without that line so hopefully that will solve the problem I was having.  I'll report back if there is still an issue.  It usually takes a few days before it stops working.

Comment: Ok good. Make sure to accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Ugh, so today I'm having the issue again.  The KDBALB is still gone.  It loads up when I type it manually but the script craps out and crashes.  I tried the .z.ts but it didn't seem to do anything.  Any other thoughts on why my script used to work all the time and now often won't?  Thanks so much for all your help on this. - q).z.ts
'.z.ts   [0]  .z.ts

Comment: Something I've noticed.  Anytime this happens and I go to restart the computer I get a message that "This app is preventing me from restarting".  I believe there is some background app or process that is running that is causing the script to crash but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Where is your stderr logging to? Also, could you keep the kdb instance open in the foreground and observe what error shows up when it crashes?

Comment: Not sure what stderr is or where the logs are.  I discovered is that if the KDB script keeps crashing I can run the command "Taskkill /IM cmd.exe /f /t" in a script and then I can run the KDB script and it will work.  I know previously if an instance of KDB is open in a CMD window and I run the script a second time it crashes.  That is why I have the Taskkill process run on a timer each night.  I think there is a hidden CMD process running in the background which is what is causing the KDB script to crash sometimes, it thinks an instance is still open.  Not sure how to find the hidden one.

Answer (score 0):

So I did finally discover what the issue was.  I had a few instances of KDB that would run via Task Scheduler in the evening and then close.  One of the instances wouldn't end and so it was continually running.  This would cause KDB to crash since there was already an instance running.  The restart would stop the process so it could be run again.  I deleted the task scheduler event and recreated it and now the event runs KDB and closes the way it is supposed to.  Thanks for all of the help in trying to figure this out!